# Unable to use jinja2 template in pip package created from python module

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, jinja2, setuptools

I have a python project with the following directory structure

```
foo
  |--MANIFEST.in
  |--requirements.txt
  |--setup.py
  |--foo.py
  |--templates/
     |--bar.tmpl
```

where `setup.py` is a python script. Previously, I was using an install script to symlink the script to my user's private `bin` (and using it with success), but decided to package it up (first time doing so). I'm able to successfully install the package in a virutalenv using `$ pip install .` from the project's root directory, and I am able to execute most of the script until I generate a template with `jinja2`. It seems as though either the `templates` dir is not getting installed with the rest of the package, or my script is not finding the path to the `templates` dir correctly.

Excerpt from `foo.py`:

```
from jinja2 import Environment, ModuleLoader

def generate_readme(template_file):
    template_env = Environment(loader=PackageLoader('foo','templates'))
    template = template_env.get_template(template_file)        
    template_vars = {"title": get_title()}
    output = template.render(template_vars)
    return output
```

**Note**: `'bar.tmpl'` is passed to this function as `template_file`

Excerpt from `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='foo',                                                         
      py_modules=['foo'],
      entry_points={'console_scripts': ['foo = foo:foo']}          
      include_package_data=True,
      zip_safe=False)
```

Contents of `MANIFEST.in`:

```
include templates/*
```

Relevant Traceback:

```
  File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/foo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/foo.py", line 30, in generate_readme
template = template_env.get_template(template_file)
  File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/foo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 812, in get_template
return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/foo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 774, in _load_template
cache_key = self.loader.get_source(self, name)[1]
  File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/foo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 235, in get_source
  raise TemplateNotFound(template)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: bar.tmpl
```

I have spent a few hours googling, reading similar stackoverflow threads, reading the jinja and setuptools docs, and reading similar code. Everything I have tested just results in the same error message, and I am somewhat at a loss. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MANIFEST.in` tell what files to include in the source distribution, i.e. `python setup.py sdist`, but it does not directly affect what files are installed because `pip install .` just calls into setuptools and doesn't do anything special with package_data.

You need to include the files in the setup.py file, either as package data or as additional files.

See https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html for details, pay attention to `data_files` and `package_data` on the page.

Comment: Thanks for the help! The templates dir gets loaded into the package now.

Now to debug jinja heh.

Comment: [Latest Python 3 version of docs](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-package-data)